# quickly reading text data into array

Tags: arrays, string, parsing, f#

I'm having difficulty reading from a text file into an array of floats using F#. The text files have lots of other data types so I can't use the CSV parser but I'm sure there must be a simple function to do this. In Python I'd just loop through all the lines of interest and append them onto an existing array using something like this: [Reading file string into an array (In a pythonic way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213336/reading-file-string-into-an-array-in-a-pythonic-way)

```py
arrays = []
i = 1
for line in open(your_file):
    if i > startOfNumericDataIndex
        new_array = np.array((array.float(i) for i in line.split(' '))) 
        arrays.append(new_array)
    i++
```

I'm trying to avoid loops in keeping with F# style but the following attempts don't work:

```
let lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path) //Collection
let linesStringArray = lines |> Seq.toArray // String array
let linesFloatArray = linesStringArray |> Array.map (fun x -> float x)
```

I get rror FS0001: This expression was expected to have type 'a list but here has type string   but I've mucked around for ages converting it to lists of strings and other types to no avail.

This method looked promising:
 [How to convert string array to float array and substitute Double.NaN for non-numeric values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410408/how-to-convert-string-array-to-float-array-and-substitute-double-nan-for-non-num): but I couldn't figure out how to use the answer given:

```
let stringLine = [| "2.0"; "3.0"; "2.0"|]    
let stringLine2Float = Array.map float stringLine
```

Just gave the error 'The type ''a list' does not match the type 'string''.

Comment: Are all of the lines just a list of space separated floats (as suggested by your python code)?

Comment: @ReedCopsey Once we get to a certain readily identifiable point in the file it's all just space separated floats thereafter. Edited python code to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid converting the lines to an array, and use `Seq.collect` to flatten all of the lines into a single sequence:

```
let lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path) //Collection
let linesFloatArray = linesStringArray 
|> Seq.skip startOfNumericDataIndex
|> Seq.collect (fun line -> line.Split(' '))
|> Seq.map (fun x -> float.Parse x)
|> Array.ofSeq
```

If you want an array of arrays, you can do:

```
let lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path) //Collection
let linesFloatArray = linesStringArray 
|> Seq.skip startOfNumericDataIndex
|> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split(' ') |> Array.map (fun x -> float.Parse(x)))
|> Array.ofSeq
```

Comment: Great thanks. I added in a call to Seq.skip(startOfNumeric) because as I mentioned to @ReedCopsey this data doesn't start till partway through the file and a Seq.filter(fun x -> x<>"") to get rid of some empty strings that were breaking the float.parse.

Comment: @arthuritus String.Split has an option where you can remove empty entries - that might be better than the extra filter.